# UK Visa Status check

Tags: visas, usa, uk, application-status

I have a US Green Card and applied for UK visa (Travel Visa) last month but haven't heard anything back from the New York Office. I am travelling on the 19th and am really concerned. They don't have any phone no. or email other than NEYOZVisaInfo@fco.gov.uk (it says incoming mail cannot be monitored).

Please assist.

Comment: @JoErNanO How is that relevant?

Comment: @Relaxed The nationality of the OP is the important criteria regarding visa application, rather than the permanent residency. And I am assuming the OP is not a US citize, since he requested a visa.

Comment: @JoErNanO But that's not what the question is about, the OP already determined he needs a visa and applied for it!

Comment: @JoErNanO it's not necessary to assume: Green card holders are by definition not nationals of the US.  If they take US citizenship, the green card becomes invalid.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of UK visas, there is nothing you can do to speed up the process or find out where you are in the processing queue.  Even internally they only have 3 or four status indicators.

Telephoning them will lead to a circular maze of recordings and menus. Emailing them (or faxing them, or posting a letter to them) will not produce a substantive result.

Having said that, once their agreed processing target has been overrun, you can then initiate a formal enquiry. Their target in the US is 12 weeks, so if you applied last month, there is approximately 8 weeks remaining before you can enquire.

Also, if you are applying as a family visitor, your UK based sponsors can write to their MP once the 12 weeks has expired. This has the paradoxical effect of slowing things down because they have to find your file and once they find it, the 12 weeks starts again on day 1.

Thus, the net answer to your question is: there's nothing you or anybody else can do until their processing target has expired.

Comment: Wow, resetting the 12 week clock on any enquiry is truly diabolical.

Comment: @GregHewgill, they will also reset it if they ask for additional documents. Resetting the window works to their advantage because it keeps their performance stats high.