# Tracking a UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, application-status, us-residents

How can I get the contact of UK visa center with the address:

> VFS services USA,
>   UKVI scanning hub
>   80 broad street floor
>   6 new York 10004

to ask for information about my visa application?

Comment: On this page [Apply for a UK visa in the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) which includes the address you mention, there is a link in section **6. Contact us** with details of call charges etc.

Comment: But don't bother. That service just charges you to read the web site to you.

Comment: Current processing time for New York is up to 30 days for visit visas. https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/new-york-united-states/visits-visas/all Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38570/uk-visa-status-check?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1):

If you’re application is taking longer than usual or you want to contact them you can do so using these details:

> #### By phone
>
> Telephone: 00 44 203 481 1736
>   Monday to Friday, 24 hours
>   Calls cost £1.37 per minute on top of your standard network charges.
>
> #### By email
>
> Email UK Visas and Immigration. 
>   Emails enquiries cost £5.48. You will not be charged for any follow-up emails about the same enquiry.

You’ll get a reply to your email within 2 days, except on Saturdays, Sundays and UK public holidays.

([Source](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english))

To contact the consulate in **an emergency** view contact details [here](https://www.gov.uk/world/organisations/british-consulate-general-new-york), note checking the process of your visa is not an emergency.

Your status **can not be checked online**:

> Online visa application tracking is NOT AVAILABLE on UK Visas and Immigration website. To know the status of your UK visa application, you must use their email or phone option, which unfortunately is NOT FREE.

([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwj2r4i-v7XkAhURolwKHeQRBBoQFjACegQICxAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com%2FHow-do-you-use-GWF-number-to-track-your-UK-visa-application&usg=AOvVaw27-JnhyfWLXvMB-aGD009Y))

Comment: While technically correct, both of these services are useless and it's not worth using them. "Wait and see" is the only good advice in this situation.